# Length of empty List in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I really don`t know why the output of the code:

```
State_Values = List[];
Print[Length[{}]]
Print[Length[State_Values]];
```

is :

```
0 
2
```

Can't suggest any reason.
Maybe it is sth very stupid, but I can't see. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Stoyan, please consider asking future questions at the dedicated Mathematica StackExchange site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You made 2 big mistakes. one is that you used _ in a variable name, the second is that you used upper case for variable name. both are a no no in Mathematica. This is so basic. Mathematica is not Matlab.

Answer (score 11):

Not stupid, but you have made a subtle mistake. The underscore in `State_Values` turns it into a `Pattern`, not a `List`. You can find this out using the function `Head[]`.

```
stateValues = List[];
Length[stateValues]
Length[{}]

Out[11]= 0

Out[12]= 0
```

As you can see, this is correct and expected. Introduce the underscore, though, and it all breaks:

```
state_Values = List[];
Length[state_Values]
Head[state_Values]
Head[stateValues]

Out[16]= 2

Out[17]= Pattern

Out[18]= List
```

It's much easier to see if you're using the GUI version of Mathematica since it highlights `Pattern` variables differently.